# sequelize secure connection for azure mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, ssl

How can I connect to Azure MySQL using sequelize?

From Azure nodejs example:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

var config =
{
    host: 'myserver4demo.mysql.database.azure.com',
    user: 'myadmin@myserver4demo',
    password: 'your_password',
    database: 'quickstartdb',
    port: 3306,
    ssl: true
};
```

what is the configuration for sequelize:

I tried using ssl but not successful:

```
ssl: true,
```

I got this error:

```
Unable to connect to database: SequelizeConnectionError: SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.
```

I got this work:

```
dialectOptions: {
      encrypt: true,
      ssl : {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    },
```

but where to find the cert?

Comment: "but not successful" is not a valid problem description. mention what fails, which error you get, etc

Comment: Unable to connect to database: SequelizeConnectionError: SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
       host: 'myserver4demo.mysql.database.azure.com',
       user: 'myadmin@myserver4demo',
       password: 'your_password',
       database: 'quickstartdb',
       port: 3306,
       ssl: {
         key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/client-key.pem'),
         cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/client-cert.pem')
       }
    });
```

**[Configure SSL connectivity in your application to securely connect to Azure Database for MySQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl)**

Comment: While this answer is one way to connect to a MySQL DB via SSL with node.js it doesn't apply Sequelize like the question asked.

Answer (score 14):

For us, the solution was to provider `dialectOptions` i.e

```
{
    "host":<hostname>,
    "port":<port>,         
    "user":<username>,
    "password":<password>,
    "port": 3306,
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "ssl": true,
    "dialectOptions": {
       "ssl": {
          "require": true
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: This is all I needed to configure as well. Thanks!

Comment: I needed 3 days .... to realize that "ssl:true" does not work, but "ssl:{require:true}" does. I am so annoyed

Answer (score 6):

The Sequelize documentation is lacking on the SSL front, and the accepted answer is not for Sequelize like the comments state.

I struggled to know how to add SSL options too, but finely found an issue on Github containing a snippet.

```
const config = {
   username: process.env["DB_USER"],
   password: process.env["DB_PASS"],
   host: process.env["DB_HOST"],
   dialect: "mysql",
   database: dbs[process.env["USE_DB"]],
   pool: {
       max: 5,
       idle: 30000,
       acquire: 60000
   },
   dialectOptions: {
       ssl: {
           ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem')
       }
   }
}
```

[The Github issue that helped me.](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11746)